# AJAX request only executes on one checkbox, need it to execute on any

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code, checkboxes are being generated by php based on the number of objects. There is one checkbox per object, and the code in the foreach that generates these is as follows (NOTE: this part is working fine, my problem is below):

```
"<input type='checkbox' name='markAsUnread' id='markRead' value='$sms->id' class='markAsUnread'>",
```

Here is the jQuery script that I am trying to use to mark any of the "clicked" boxes as "read". This particular script works when the first box is clicked at any time, but I need it to work for any of the boxes clicked (second, third, etc). I only need it to work on one at a time, but I need it to do so with any one selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myEl = document.getElementById('markRead');

    myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var bloop = $('#markRead').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/link/to/route',
            data: {sms: bloop}, 
            success: function(data) {                           
                window.location = '/foo/bar';},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }, false);
</script>
```

I assume that it is not working because it is only grabbing the first box, so what needs to be changed to make it work with any of the selected checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it, iterating over the elements and adding a click listener within the iterator seemed to do the trick:

```
    $(function(){
        var myElements = document.getElementsByName('markAsUnread');
        $.each(myElements, function (index){
            $(this).on("click", function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/foo/bar',
                    data: {sms: $(this).val()}, 
                    success: function(data) {                           
                        window.location = '/back/home';},
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

I also removed IDs from the PHP generated checkboxes, as I wasn't using them.

Answer (score 1):

That should not work. If you repeatedly create elements with the same id, you violate html rules. There can only be one.

Instead of applying the function to only one element, identified with an ID, as

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('markRead');
```

ask for all elements with the name "markRead":

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByName('markRead');
```

which gives you an array to iterate over.

Additionally change your jquery-selector from

```
$('#markRead')
```

to

```
$("[name=markRead]")
```

Also, make sure that id-values are actually unique within one html document.

Comment: No. He needs to change the `document.getElementById('markRead');` part. Really though it's bad practice to have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: OP is still going to have issues with this answer since you do noe explain you would need to loop and changing it to access the val() will pull the first one, not what was clicked.

Comment: Also, if all the checkbox have to share the same name, it will probably make more sense to use `name="markRead[]"` so that PHP can parse the array of checkboxes when the form is submitted (if that happens, that is).

Comment: My JavaScript is terrible, I appreciate any input. I am setting it so that the ids are the individual SMS ids. Is that good practice?

Answer (score 1):

try following script and check

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
     var myElements = $('input[name=markAsUnread]');

    myElements.click(function() {
        var bloop = $('input[name=markAsUnread]:checked').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/link/to/route',
            data: {sms: bloop}, 
            success: function(data) {                           
                window.location = '/foo/bar';},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }, false);

    });
</script>
```

Also, remove ID attribute from your generated checkboxes or make it Unique instead of having same value for all elements.

Comment: `myElements.click(function() { ...`?

Comment: I think that line `var bloop = ...` needs more work, but we will see what OP says

Comment: OK, so I changed the code to this and now none of the boxes are clickable/selectable. No errors on Chrome dev tools